# gdb python : How to redirect the output of a gdb command to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdb, gdb-python

I am using RHEL 5.3 OS, `gdb` 7.5 and `python` 2.7.
I am writing a script in Python to automate some gdb debugging steps.
Can we store the output of the following command ("name1") into a variable?

```
(gdb) p *(ptr->name)
$13 = "name1"
```

I want to do this because in my Python script I will compare this (`name1`) to a user input string, and if matches, will do some action otherwise ask user to input another string.

Please Suggest me alternative if it is not possible.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I got it wrong. Do you want gdb to return the value to the script? My answer assigns the value do a gdb variable only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the value of an expression in GDB is what **gdb.parse_and_eval()** is for. I think you want something like this:

**name1.c** :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* https://github.com/scottt/debugbreak */
#include <debugbreak/debugbreak.h>

struct T {
    char *name;
};

int main()
{
    struct T t, *p = &t;
    t.name = strdup("name1");
    debug_break();
    printf("%s\n", p->name);
    return 0;
}
```

**input-name.py** :

```
import gdb

gdb.execute('set python print-stack full')
gdb.execute('set confirm off')
gdb.execute('file name1')
gdb.execute('run')

name_in_program = gdb.parse_and_eval('p->name').string()
gdb.write('Please input name: ')
name = raw_input()
while name != name_in_program:
    gdb.write('Please try another name: ')
    name = raw_input()

gdb.execute('quit')
```

Sample session:

```
$ gdb -q -x input-name.py

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
main () at name1.c:16
16      printf("%s\n", p->name);
Please input name: nameX
Please try another name: name1

$
```

Note that I took the shortcut of breaking into the debugger by inserting a trap instruction in my C code via **debug_break()**. You'd probably want to set a breakpoint instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You always do things very nicely. Great..:-)

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: sorry, made a mistake with the expression. Correction:**

See the [gdb documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html#Convenience-Vars).

To set a **convenience variable** you can use this expression:
`set $yourVar = (gdb) p *(ptr->name)`

You can then access your new variable like so:
`print $yourVar`

The output will look similar to this:

```
(gdb) set $foo = "bar"
(gdb) print $foo
$1 = "bar"
(gdb)
```

Comment: Leske ,Can you please justify your answer? How it will be executed inside gdb prompt?